# How can the intel system instructions be run on linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

Using 7th gen i5 processor, nasm, ld.

Written using general purpose registers and system calls, the program runs on Ubuntu. An example is a simple hello world program.

```
global _start


section .text
    _start:

        mov eax, 0x4                ; write(int fd, char *buf, int len)
        mov ebx, 0x1                ; fd
        mov ecx, message            ; *buf
        mov edx, message_length     ; len
        int 0x80                    ; syscall

        mov eax, 0x1                ; exit(int status)
        mov ebx, 0x0                ; status
        int 0x80                    ; syscall
    



section .data
    message db "hello world", 0xA
    message_length equ $-message
```

```
nasm -f elf64 -o hello_world.o hello_world.s
ld hello_world.o -o hello_world
./hello_world
```

output: `hello_world`

However, the program written using the intel system instructions does not work.

```
global _start



section .text
    _start:
        CLI
        HLT
```

```
nasm -f elf64 halt.s -o halt.o
ld halt.o -o halt
./halt
```

output: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

1. What prevents this code from compiling this way and running?
2. How can this code be compiled and run?

Comment: The OS prevents it. It's the job of the kernel to stop you from doing things that could interfere with the operation of the system or other processes unless you are authorized to do that. To run `cli` and `hlt` you need to be root and have [io privileges](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/iopl.2.html)

Answer (score 5):

You have two questions:

1. > What prevents this code from compiling this way and running?

   Nothing prevents it from *assembling*, because it is valid code.
   The reason that *it does not run*/*throws a segmentation fault* is, that you are attempting to run instructions that require certain privileges in user mode.

   Have a look at [HLT](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/hlt) which description states

   > The HLT instruction is a privileged instruction.

   Also look at [CLI](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cli#tbl-3-7)/STI, whose situation is more complicated (which is explained in the below article and the comments below), but is also *mostly* useful for *kernel mode* code. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_flag#Privilege_level) says

   > In all three cases, only privileged applications (usually the OS kernel) may modify IF[Interrupt flag]. [...] CLI and STI are [also] privileged instructions, which trigger a general protection fault if an unprivileged application attempts to execute it, [...]

   That should answer your question regarding the difference between these two instructions and why *HLT* surely generates a GPF (General Protection Fault) executed in *User Mode*.
2. > How can this code be compiled and run?

   The only way to run this code is in privileged mode. So on Windows or Linux you'd have to code a *kernel driver* or code your own OS to make sensible use of these instructions.

The above only applies to [*Protected Mode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode) or [*Long Mode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode) code.
(Real mode code may always modify IF, the *Interrupt flag*)

Comment: The CLI checks IOPL. You don't need to be in ring0 for that. Apparently you do for HLT.

Comment: Linux gives you `iopl()`. Still, that won't work for HLT.

Comment: A privileged user under Linux can call the function `iopl` and set it to 3 and then `CLI` and `STI` can be used https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/iopl.2.html. `HLT` though is unaffected by IOPL and will raise #GP if CPL  != 0.

Comment: Michael. Thanks for comment. :)
While investigating the CPL (Current privilege level) case, I came across a table called GDTR. Could you recommend an emulator to run these system instructions?